# Call web api url using jquery ajax from an asp.net web form page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms, jquery-ajax

I have a web api method which is url is the following:

> [https://www.mycompany.es/webapi/deptartment/search/{partialDepartmentName}](https://www.mycompany.es/webapi/deptartment/search/%7BpartialDepartmentName%7D)

This web api method returns a JSON with all the department names containing partialDepartmentName.

I have checked using Telerik Fiddler Classic by typing below url to search departments which contains "finance" (without doble quotes) in the composer and using a GET verb (POST is not working).

> https://www.mycompany.es/webapi/deptartment/search/finance

and it works ok. Now I want to do the same using a jQuery ajax call from my asp.net web form page as below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.mycompany.es/webapi/deptartment/search/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { "finance" } ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

but it does not work? what am i doing wrong? sorry, i am newbie in web development...

Comment: In what way does this not work?  Using your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  Is the AJAX request made in the network tab?  What is the server's response?  What result do you observe from this code?

Comment: try using response.d  ("d" is data returned - and it is a "qurik" of asp.net).

Comment: Why do you use POST in your jQuery when you wrote it doesn’t work in Fiddler? Change type to GET and add “finance” to the end of URL.

Comment: @RomanK. Yes, this what the problem. Replacing POST by GET works. I am newbie in web programming. What is the difference between POST and GET when calling a web api method? Fiddler was failing using POST but working using GET.

Comment: Ralph, I'm glad it's working. Comment section is probably not be the place to discuss differences among HTTP methods. Basically, POST allows you to send data to the web server, whereas GET is used to request the data. There are numerous tutorials and explanations on the web. You can start with [POST (HTTP) on Wikipeadia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)). It's not necessary that an API supports both methods.

Answer (score 1):

Does the web method need/expect parmaters (looks like no).

So:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.mycompany.es/webapi/deptartment/search/finance.aspx',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "" } ,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Note how we used ".d" - that gets you the data response in asp.net